# HOBT vs OBJECT in Extended Event lock_escalation resource_type field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, extended-events

I'm capturing the `lock_escalation` event on our production servers (running the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2014) and trying to make sense of the output, particularly the `resource_type` field.  Although there are 17 different possible values for the `resource_type` field, all I see is `OBJECT` and `HOBT`.  On some servers I only see `OBJECT`, but on one I see `HOBT` quite a lot.

What is SQL Server trying to tell me with that field?  All of our tables, on all servers, are currently configured with `LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE`, which we are considering changing.  The server where I see `HOBT` so often has many more partitioned tables than our other servers, but, from what I understand and given our configuration, SQL Server should only be escalating to the table level and not to the partition level.

I am quite certain that all of our tables are configured with `LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE`.  I ran this query in the database where I am seeing so many `HOBT` results:

```
SELECT lock_escalation_desc, total = COUNT(*)
    FROM sys.tables
    GROUP BY lock_escalation_desc
```

And I got one row:

```
lock_escalation_desc  total
TABLE                 143
```

(That particular database is so enormous that it basically gets its own server.)

---

EDIT:  I'm pretty sure now that `OBJECT` indicates a table lock and `HOBT` indicates a partition-level lock.  But I am very surprised to see the partition-level locking, because the tables involved are not configured to be locked that way, and [everything I've read indicates that SQL Server should be locking at the table level](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx).

Here is the full XML for one of the events:

```
<event name="lock_escalation" package="sqlserver" timestamp="2017-06-08T18:00:23.590Z">
  <data name="resource_type">
    <type name="lock_resource_type" package="sqlserver"></type>
    <value>12</value>
    <text><![CDATA[HOBT]]></text>
  </data>
  <data name="mode">
    <type name="lock_mode" package="sqlserver"></type>
    <value>5</value>
    <text><![CDATA[X]]></text>
  </data>
  <data name="owner_type">
    <type name="lock_owner_type" package="sqlserver"></type>
    <value>1</value>
    <text><![CDATA[Transaction]]></text>
  </data>
  <data name="transaction_id">
    <type name="int64" package="package0"></type>
    <value>10067714031</value>
  </data>
  <data name="database_id">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>8</value>
  </data>
  <data name="lockspace_workspace_id">
    <type name="ptr" package="package0"></type>
    <value>0x0000004e491a1e50</value>
  </data>
  <data name="lockspace_sub_id">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>4</value>
  </data>
  <data name="lockspace_nest_id">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>1</value>
  </data>
  <data name="resource_0">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>38609</value>
  </data>
  <data name="resource_1">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>256</value>
  </data>
  <data name="resource_2">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>0</value>
  </data>
  <data name="escalation_cause">
    <type name="lock_escalation_cause" package="sqlserver"></type>
    <value>0</value>
    <text><![CDATA[Lock threshold]]></text>
  </data>
  <data name="object_id">
    <type name="int32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>1052582838</value>
  </data>
  <data name="hobt_id">
    <type name="uint64" package="package0"></type>
    <value>72057596568207360</value>
  </data>
  <data name="escalated_lock_count">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>6248</value>
  </data>
  <data name="hobt_lock_count">
    <type name="uint32" package="package0"></type>
    <value>6247</value>
  </data>
  <data name="statement">
    <type name="unicode_string" package="package0"></type>
    <value><![CDATA[(@accountId int, @date int, @basisId int)DELETE FROM StatFxLotCumulativeActivity WHERE accountId = @accountId AND reportDate > @date]]></value>
  </data>
  <data name="database_name">
    <type name="unicode_string" package="package0"></type>
    <value><![CDATA[aws_db]]></value>
  </data>
</event>
```

When I query the system views for the `object_id`/`hobt_id` pair referenced in that event:

```
select * from sys.tables where object_id = 1052582838
select * from sys.partitions where hobt_id = 72057596568207360
```

It seems clear to me that the table involved is partitioned and has a clustered index:

```
name                        object_id  principal_id schema_id parent_object_id type type_desc  create_date             modify_date             is_ms_shipped is_published is_schema_published lob_data_space_id filestream_data_space_id max_column_id_used lock_on_bulk_load uses_ansi_nulls is_replicated has_replication_filter is_merge_published is_sync_tran_subscribed has_unchecked_assembly_data text_in_row_limit large_value_types_out_of_row is_tracked_by_cdc lock_escalation lock_escalation_desc is_filetable is_memory_optimized durability durability_desc
--------------------------- ---------- ------------ --------- ---------------- ---- ---------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------- ------------ ------------------- ----------------- ------------------------ ------------------ ----------------- --------------- ------------- ---------------------- ------------------ ----------------------- --------------------------- ----------------- ---------------------------- ----------------- --------------- -------------------- ------------ ------------------- ---------- ---------------
StatFxLotCumulativeActivity 1052582838 NULL         1         0                U    USER_TABLE 2015-02-19 10:24:19.463 2017-02-21 14:06:03.857 0             0            0                   0                 NULL                     10                 0                 1               0             0                      0                  0                       0                           0                 0                            0                 0               TABLE                0            0                   0          SCHEMA_AND_DATA

partition_id      object_id  index_id partition_number hobt_id           rows      filestream_filegroup_id data_compression data_compression_desc
----------------- ---------- -------- ---------------- ----------------- --------- ----------------------- ---------------- ---------------------
72057596568207360 1052582838 1        32               72057596568207360 982143818 0                       2                PAGE
```

The table has 126 partitions, but only 13 have any rows.  Running this query:

```
select * from sys.partitions where object_id = 1052582838 and rows > 0
```

Gives me this:

```
partition_number hobt_id              rows
---------------- -------------------- --------------------
18               72057596141502464    34861
21               72057596141699072    89201
22               72057596141764608    573135
23               72057596141830144    471881
24               72057596141895680    1776464
26               72057596142026752    9463538
25               72057596299771904    1454117
27               72057596359606272    3748776
28               72057596360327168    2650215
29               72057596361048064    2700981
30               72057596361179136    448102594
31               72057596361310208    1375155391
32               72057596568207360    998318651
```

Here's the SSMS-generated DDL for the table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[StatLotCumulativeActivity](
    [accountId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [reportDate] [int] NOT NULL,
    [awsId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [value] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [activityType] [int] NOT NULL,
    [balanceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sourceOriginalTransactionId] [int] NULL,
    [basisId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sourceSecurityId] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo_StatLotCumulativeActivity] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [accountId] ASC,
    [reportDate] ASC,
    [awsId] ASC,
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

Comment: with lock escalation=table,sql server should lock at table level,not at partition level,are you sure of `LOCK_ESCALATION = TABLE` setting on the servers where you are seeing `hobt` locks more

Comment: @TheGameiswar, I've edited my question to include my method for checking our LOCK_ESCALATION settings.

Comment: Do you have heaps in this server?

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, I do have a few, but they are unused.  I have spot-checked a few of the `object_id` and `hobt_id` values from the events being returned, and they map to partitioned tables with clustered indexes.  However, the SQL text in the `statement` field creates temporary tables that don't have clustered indexes.  But if they're the culprit then I would expect the `object_id` and `hobt_id` values to be for those temporary tables.

Comment: @SqlWorldWide, most but not all of the statements include references to temporary tables.  A few of them are simple `DELETE FROM ...` statements involving our normal (but partitioned) tables.

Comment: @sam.bishop Keep in mind that Lock Escalation typically happens at 3000 lock requests, so you aren't looking for single-row DML changes. And for the SQL text, are you given a `statement_start_offset` and `end_offset`, and if so, are you using them to find the specific query within the batch? Again, it would really super help if you posted the lock escalation report XML in the question.

Comment: @srutzky, what I've read indicates that the threshold is 5000.  Unfortunately the event only includes the batch text, without any offsets.  But I found an example where there is only one statement in the batch, which I've added to my question.

Comment: @sam.bishop Yes, probably 5000, I sometimes mix those two up for some odd reason. Thanks for posting the full XML. It does indicate that the escalation was due to exceeding that threshold. Does this partition (ID = 32) have most of the data, or is the data spread out?

Comment: @srutzky, it's the second largest partition.  I've added more detail to my question.

Comment: @sam.bishop For that Clustered Index, do you have Row Locks and/or Page Locks disabled? Also are you seeing "OBJECT" for other partitioned tables?

Comment: @srutzky, neither lock types are disabled.  (I've added the DDL above.)  I've seen both `OBJECT` as well as `HOBT` for a number of tables in my event stream, though not with any discernible pattern.

Comment: @srutzky, I have a theory.  The table referenced in the example `DELETE` is partitioned into ranges of account IDs.  Locking at the partition level only increases the chance of deadlock if you lock more than one partition at a time.  It could be that SQL Server knows that it's safe to lock at the partition level here because it would never lock more than one partition.  (The `DELETE` will only ever reference one account.)  I'll look into this more tomorrow.

Answer (score 4):

You shouldn't need to guess at this. According to the documentation for [sys.dm_tran_locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-tran-locks-transact-sql#resource-details) (under "Resource Details"), it shows that:

> HOBT

means:

> Represents a heap or a B-tree. These are the basic access path structures.

and the "resource_associated_entity_id" field (that should be there or should be added) value relates to:

> HoBt ID. This value corresponds to **sys.partitions.hobt_id**.

Meaning, plug the "resource_associated_entity_id" value into:

```
-- run this in the DB where the object exists
SELECT OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sp.[object_id]) AS [SchemaName],
       OBJECT_NAME(sp.[object_id]) AS [ObjectName],
       si.[name] AS [IndexName],
       *
FROM   sys.partitions sp
INNER JOIN sys.indexes si
        ON si.[object_id] = sp.[object_id]
       AND si.[index_id] = sp.[index_id]
WHERE  sp.[hobt_id] = <reported_hobt_id>;
```

Some additional resources:

- [Lock Escalation (Database Engine)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Enabling Partition Level Locking in SQL Server 2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/03/03/enabling-partition-level-locking-in-sql-server-2008/)
- [Lock:Escalation Event Class](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190723(v=sql.120).aspx)

Comment: My question isn't very clear, but if I edited it further then the comments probably wouldn't make sense.  I have two questions.  Does `OBJECT` indicate a table lock and `HOBT` a partition-level lock?  And if so, why is it that partition-level locks are being taken when [Microsoft's documentation would indicate that table-level locks would be taken instead](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184286(v=sql.105).aspx)?  (And to be clear, partition-level locks are what I want, but I just don't expect to see them given our configuration.)

Comment: @sam.bishop The documentation does say that `OBJECT` would be Table, View, etc, but less clear about `HOBT` outside of it being an index but not a "page" or "row" specifically. So maybe could be partition? I do see your reply to SqlWorldWide and that info should be added to the question. It would also help if you could include the "subtype" or state that it was empty, and please include the SQL text that you mentioned. Basically post the full XML in the question, please :)

Comment: there's no "subtype" information in the `lock_escalation` event, unfortunately.  But I've added the full XML to my question.